# Integral Equations where the Unknown Function depends on the Integration Dummy

Tags: conditional-expectation, integral-equations

Consider the following the integral equation:
$$ f(s) = \int_a^b K(s,t) g(s,t) dt, $$
where $f$ and $K$ are known functions, and $g$ is the unknown function we want to solve for.

---

For example, $K(s,t)$ is the conditional density of a random variable $T$ given $S$. So $K \geq 0$ and $\int K(s,t)dt = 1$. Then the question becomes: if we know the conditional expectation
$$ \mathbb{E}[g(S,T) \mid S] = f(S), $$
then can we back out the original function $g$?

---

Is there any way to solve this kind of problem? All the books I find talking about integral equations do not allow $g$ to be a function of $s$. I'm really curious about this more general situation where $g$ is a function of both $t$ and $s$ but couldn't find any reference to go to.

Thanks in advance for any help and consideration!

Comment: Is there a particular specification of $f$ and $K$ you want to solve? If yes, post it.

Comment: @Snoop Thanks for the reminder! I edited the question to include an example of using conditional expectation to back out the original function.